# 2 Statements with OR in a do while loop

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I want to end this `Do While` loop if the the `pulls` are 0 or the time is on 60 `sek`.

But if the `pulls` are at 0 the loop doesn't stop.

```
do{

    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        sek++;
        System.out.println(sek);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    db = new BdsPostgres( );
    db.select(Result.SET_1, "SELECT * FROM connection_overview WHERE leitung="+leitung+" AND  status='pull' ");
    db.naechsterDatensatz(Result.SET_1);

    anzahlPulls = db.leseZeilen(Result.SET_1);
    db.schliessen();

} while (anzahlPulls != 0 || sek != 60);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `and` instead of `or` , please note in `while` loop if the condition evaluates to true, it continues the loop, does not end it.

So actually your condition reads as - while either (anzahlPulls is not zero) or (sek is not 60) continue the loop. (that is when one of the condition is true continue the loop)

You actually want to use `and` - while both (anzajlPulls is not zero) and (sek is not 60) continue the loop. (that is break the loop when one of the conditions becomes false)

Example code -

```
do{

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                sek++;
                System.out.println(sek);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            db = new BdsPostgres( );
                db.select(Result.SET_1, "SELECT * FROM connection_overview WHERE leitung="+leitung+" AND  status='pull' ");  
                db.naechsterDatensatz(Result.SET_1);

                anzahlPulls = db.leseZeilen(Result.SET_1);
            db.schliessen();

        }while (anzahlPulls != 0 && sek != 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got your logic wrong:

NOT ( A OR B ) =  (NOT A) AND (NOT B)